# How do I Add a sequence column to a Dask dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dask

I have the following dask dataframe

```
a b c
1 a 30
1 a 11 
2 b 99
2 b 55
3 c 21
4 d 21
```

I want to sequence the duplicate rows based on the size of the row's c field below is example output

```
a b c  seq
1 a 30 2
1 a 11 1
2 b 99 2
2 b 55 1
3 c 21 1
4 d 21 1
```

Is there an easy way to do this in dask?

Before you ask, I'm replicating an existing process and I don't know why the duplicate rows are sequenced using the c field.

Answer (score 0):

Try with `rank`

```
df['new'] = df.groupby('a')['c'].rank().astype(int)
Out[29]: 
0    2
1    1
2    2
3    1
4    1
5    1
Name: c, dtype: int32
```